# How to perform multiple linear model fits of one column against all (pairwise) using dplyr and broom

Tags: r, tidyverse, linear-regression, broom

Given the `mtcars` data:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

What I want to do is to perform linear fit with `y = mpg` as the outcome with all other variables as predictors `x` , in one on one basis (i.e. from `mpg ~ cyl` up to `mpg ~ carb`).

How can I do that with dplyr?

So far I have this code (as suggested by Maurits):

```
 library(broom)
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)
 lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% 
 # glance() # this fail
 tidy()
```

It gave me this result:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 5
   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)  12.3      18.7        0.657  0.518 
 2 cyl          -0.111     1.05      -0.107  0.916 
 3 disp          0.0133    0.0179     0.747  0.463 
 4 hp           -0.0215    0.0218    -0.987  0.335 
 5 drat          0.787     1.64       0.481  0.635 
 6 wt           -3.72      1.89      -1.96   0.0633
 7 qsec          0.821     0.731      1.12   0.274 
 8 vs            0.318     2.10       0.151  0.881 
 9 am            2.52      2.06       1.23   0.234 
10 gear          0.655     1.49       0.439  0.665 
11 carb         -0.199     0.829     -0.241  0.812
```

But when I do

```
> tidy(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars))
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    37.9      2.07      18.3  8.37e-18
2 cyl            -2.88     0.322     -8.92 6.11e-10
```

Notice the difference in estimate from -2.88 to -0.11.

Comment: Do you mean `lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>% tidy()`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I tried that (see update) but it gave error `Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  is.atomic(x) is not TRUE`

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Just use `lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)` and then pipe this into `tidy`. No `mutate`, no `list` necessary.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I tried your approach. But it's not consistent with the result when I do manual pairwise `tidy(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars))` gives estimate  -2.88, but your approach: -0.111.

Comment: Well yes of course it would give different results. In `mpg ~ .` you are accounting for all variables as confounders, whereas in `mpg ~ cyl` you only account for `cyl`. The models are entirely different, and estimates will be *completely* different.

Comment: @MauritsEvers what I meant in OP was one-on-one (`mpg ~ cyl, mpg ~disp, etc`). How can I do it?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. So you want to *successively* regress `mpg` on all other variables one-by-one? If so, my question would be "why?". This is dangerous territory for e.g. variable selection/importance estimation.

Comment: @MauritsEvers exactly! I've updated my OP for clarification.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? This is potentially dangerous territory, if variable selection or variable importance quantification is your goal... Instead, you can study marginal effects of every variable from the full model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246217/discussion-between-scamander-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reshape, groupby and then do the lm:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  pivot_longer(-mpg) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(broom::tidy(lm(mpg~value, cur_data())), .groups='drop')

 name  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 am    (Intercept)  17.1      1.12       15.2   1.13e-15
 2 am    value         7.24     1.76        4.11  2.85e- 4
 3 carb  (Intercept)  25.9      1.84       14.1   9.22e-15
 4 carb  value        -2.06     0.569      -3.62  1.08e- 3
 5 cyl   (Intercept)  37.9      2.07       18.3   8.37e-18
 6 cyl   value        -2.88     0.322      -8.92  6.11e-10
 7 disp  (Intercept)  29.6      1.23       24.1   3.58e-21
 8 disp  value        -0.0412   0.00471    -8.75  9.38e-10
 9 drat  (Intercept)  -7.52     5.48       -1.37  1.80e- 1
10 drat  value         7.68     1.51        5.10  1.78e- 5
11 gear  (Intercept)   5.62     4.92        1.14  2.62e- 1
12 gear  value         3.92     1.31        3.00  5.40e- 3
13 hp    (Intercept)  30.1      1.63       18.4   6.64e-18
14 hp    value        -0.0682   0.0101     -6.74  1.79e- 7
15 qsec  (Intercept)  -5.11    10.0        -0.510 6.14e- 1
16 qsec  value         1.41     0.559       2.53  1.71e- 2
17 vs    (Intercept)  16.6      1.08       15.4   8.85e-16
18 vs    value         7.94     1.63        4.86  3.42e- 5
19 wt    (Intercept)  37.3      1.88       19.9   8.24e-19
20 wt    value        -5.34     0.559      -9.56  1.29e-10
```

If only interested in the coefficient values, you can directly use base R:

```
lm(mpg~ind/values+0, cbind(mpg=mtcars$mpg,stack(mtcars, -mpg)))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ ind/values + 0, data = cbind(mpg = mtcars$mpg, 
    stack(mtcars, -mpg)))

Coefficients:
        indcyl         inddisp           indhp         inddrat           indwt  
      37.88458        29.59985        30.09886        -7.52462        37.28513  
       indqsec           indvs           indam         indgear         indcarb  
      -5.11404        16.61667        17.14737         5.62333        25.87233  
 indcyl:values  inddisp:values    indhp:values  inddrat:values    indwt:values  
      -2.87579        -0.04122        -0.06823         7.67823        -5.34447  
indqsec:values    indvs:values    indam:values  indgear:values  indcarb:values  
       1.41212         7.94048         7.24494         3.92333        -2.05572
```

Note that the `indVAR` is the intercept of the variable and `indVAR:value` is the coefficient. eg intercept for cyl = `37.88458` while the coefficient for cyl = `-2.87579`. This is the same results given by the tidyverse function

Comment: Great answer. If I want to have only R2 values, how can we do that in `tidy` way?

Comment: @BappaDas consider doing `R2=summary(lm(mpg~value, cur_data()))$r.squared`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
data(mtcars)

x = names(mtcars[,-1])
out <- unlist(lapply(1, function(n) combn(x, 1, FUN=function(row) paste0("mpg ~ ", paste0(row, collapse = "+")))))
out

#>  [1] "mpg ~ cyl"  "mpg ~ disp" "mpg ~ hp"   "mpg ~ drat" "mpg ~ wt"  
#>  [6] "mpg ~ qsec" "mpg ~ vs"   "mpg ~ am"   "mpg ~ gear" "mpg ~ carb"

library(broom)
library(dplyr)

#To have the regression coefficients
tmp1 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
  a = tidy(lm(frml, data=mtcars))
  a$frml = frml
  return(a)
}))
head(tmp1)

#To have the regression results i.e. R2, AIC, BIC
tmp2 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
  a = glance(lm(frml, data=mtcars))
  a$frml = frml
  return(a)
}))
head(tmp2)

write.csv(tmp1, "Try_lm_coefficients.csv")
write.csv(tmp2, "Try_lm_results.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
idx_var <- which(!names(mtcars) %in% "mpg") %>% set_names(names(mtcars)[.])
idx_res <- which(names(mtcars) %in% "mpg")

map_dfr(
    idx_var, 
    ~ tidy(lm(mtcars[[idx_res]] ~ mtcars[[.x]])),
    .id = "variable")
## A tibble: 20 x 6
#   variable term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#   <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 cyl      (Intercept)   37.9      2.07       18.3   8.37e-18
# 2 cyl      mtcars[[.x]]  -2.88     0.322      -8.92  6.11e-10
# 3 disp     (Intercept)   29.6      1.23       24.1   3.58e-21
# 4 disp     mtcars[[.x]]  -0.0412   0.00471    -8.75  9.38e-10
# 5 hp       (Intercept)   30.1      1.63       18.4   6.64e-18
# 6 hp       mtcars[[.x]]  -0.0682   0.0101     -6.74  1.79e- 7
# 7 drat     (Intercept)   -7.52     5.48       -1.37  1.80e- 1
# 8 drat     mtcars[[.x]]   7.68     1.51        5.10  1.78e- 5
# 9 wt       (Intercept)   37.3      1.88       19.9   8.24e-19
#10 wt       mtcars[[.x]]  -5.34     0.559      -9.56  1.29e-10
#...
```